# Creating a list of tuples using list comprehension based on input in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'd like to create a list of tuples with list comprehension based on inputing the elements of the tuples. I did it like this:

```
list_tuples = []

for _ in range(int(input()):

  c = tuple(map(float, input('ingrese x, y, z del punto: ' + str(_ + 1)).split(',')))

  list_tuples.append((c))
```

this gets me the job done, but i'd like to do it with list comprehension, is it possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension is really straightforward, when you already have a simple `for` loop like this. You just put the clauses in the opposite order, basically:

```
list_tuples = [
    tuple(map(float, input('ingrese x, y, z del punto: ' + str(_ + 1)).split(',')))
    for _ in range(int(input()))
]
```

---

As a sidenote, I would avoid using `_` as a variable name unless you actually don't need to use the variable for anything (which isn't the case here, as you're using it inside the `str()` call). Instead, convention for loops is to use a single-letter variable, say, `i`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the list comprehension equivalent to your code:

`list_tuples = [tuple(map(float, input('ingrese x, y, z del punto: ' + str(_ + 1)).split(','))) for _ in range(int(input()))]`

(But I think the original is more comprehensible!)